# Is listening to music bad for moksha?

Tags: shiva, krishna, moksha, sadhana, gandharva

Many people listen to music,this is a fact,Carnatic Music being one among them.

A spiritual aspirant is advised to shun all sense pleasing actions.

Since listening to music that he/she likes,automatically gives him some pleasure(said music is **not centered on his/her ishta,or conducive for his spiritual practices)**

In this situation,**should he shun this music?**

Or **is listening to *any* music,Carnatic or otherwise,an impediment in the path of moksha?**

(I have added the tags “shiva” and “Krishna “,as they are associated with music in the scriptures,as Muralidhar and Veenadhar respectively;
“Gandharvas” are known for music,so I have added them as well)

Comment: No, Moksha comes from Self-realization/Atman gyan. All the worldly objects,senses including physical body are temporary and created by Self and for Self to know Self.  https://www.ananda.org/blog/yogananda-sukdeva-byasa-gita/

Comment: In the Bhakti Yoga, singing and listening to the musical glories of the lord is one of the best. So, NO - it's not a sin. Plus, music relaxes the mind, and following one's body's natural needs is not a sin It's like asking - *"Isn't feeling hungry to fill my 'material-stomach' a sin? since we are pleasing our taste buds while eating food."*. And FYI: Almost every act generates good or bad karma, one can't just keep balancing them throughout day - thats a waste of life provived by the Providence. - कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते.....

Comment: Music can raise or lower your consciousness, as it generates vibrations. The answer depends upon the kind of music listened to.